# axios can't accept response data sent by Spring Boot controller

Tags: spring-boot, vue.js

I tried to integrate vue.js with Spring Boot. This is my vue.js code:

```
<template>
// ...
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Login",
  data: function() {
      return {
          username: '',
          password: '',
          msg: ''
      }
  },
  methods: {
      // post data to Spring Boot
      login() {
          axios.post('/login',{
              username: this.username,
              password: this.password
          })
          .then(function(response) {
              if(response.data.code === 200){
                this.$store.dispatch('setCurrentUser',this.username);
                // vue-route
                this.$router.push('/course');
              } else {
                  this.msg = response.message;
              }
          })
          .catch(function(err) {
              this.msg = 'error';
          });
      }
  }
};
</script>
```

And this is my Spring Boot controller:

```
@RestController
@ResponseBody
public class LoginController {

    @Autowired
    private ResultGenerator resultGenerator;

    @PostMapping("/login")
    public RestResult login(String username, String password){
        if(username.equals("123") && password.equals("123")){
            return resultGenerator.getSuccessResult();
        } else {
            return resultGenerator.getFailResult("error");
        }
    }
}
```

The controller will return JSON data which looks like:`{"code":200,"message":"success","data":null}`. When the `login` method was called, controller could accept the username and password and controller sent response data too. But that was all and vue-router didn't  work. All I saw in the brower was:
[image]

Can anyone help?
------------------ Addition -----------------------
This is vue-router config:

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    component: Login
  },
  {
    path: '/signin',
    component: Signin
  },
  {
    path: '/course',
    component: Course
  }
];

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes,
  mode: "history"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be that you return resultGenerator.getSuccessResult(). Have you tried redirecting to the '/course' path inside Spring Boot Controller?

```
 @PostMapping("/login")
    public RestResult login(String username, String password){
        if(username.equals("123") && password.equals("123")){
            this.$router.push('/course');
        } else {
            return resultGenerator.getFailResult("error");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If the Vue.js and Spring boot are 2 different apps (like backend and frontend), this may help:

Try using @CrossOrigin (CORS) on your @controller or on the method that expose the rest, I had similar issues on an Ionic 3 proyect and thaty solved the problem.

EXAMPLE:

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:9000")
@GetMapping("/greeting")
public Greeting greeting(@RequestParam(required=false, defaultValue="World") String name) {
    System.out.println("==== in greeting ====");
    return new Greeting(counter.incrementAndGet(), String.format(template, name));
}
```

It should look something like this:

```
@RestController
```

@ResponseBody
public class LoginController {

```
@Autowired
private ResultGenerator resultGenerator;

@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:9000") // The IP:PORT of the vue app origin
@PostMapping("/login")
public RestResult login(String username, String password){
    if(username.equals("123") && password.equals("123")){
        return resultGenerator.getSuccessResult();
    } else {
        return resultGenerator.getFailResult("error");
    }
}
```

}

[Source from spring.io Here! :D](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/)